# Как получить результат Windows_x64 сообщения в Qt5?

Tags: c++, windows, qt5, x86-64, qt6

В Qt5 функция для обработки сообщений винды имеет вид:

```
bool QWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
```

и в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) сказано, что 3 параметр на винде означает [`LRESULT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types). В Qt6 же параметр [меняется](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) на [`qintptr`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qintptr-typedef):

```
bool QWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, qintptr *result)
```

Теперь действительно можно передать 64-битный `LRESULT` через 64-битный `qintptr`. Но что делать на 64-битной системе с [32-битным `long`](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:35,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:35,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:35,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:35,startLineNumber:1),source:%27int+main()+%7B+return+sizeof(long)%3B+%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) в Qt5?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества что именно непонятно?

Comment: @Stas, наверное непонятно  что вас смущает. Просто передать long*, а в функции кастить, если нужно

Comment: @ARHovsepyan смущает то, что `LRESULT` на Winx64 64-битный, а `long` - 32битный => каст теряет значение (например, в вызове `*result = SendMessage(...)`, где `SendMessage` - WinAPI функция, возвращающая `LRESULT`)

Comment: Смотрели https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qintptr-typedef ?

Comment: @gil9red ну в моём вопросе есть эта ссылка, так что да, смотрел

Comment: @Stas,  это понятно, но вопрос вы задаете не только для себя,  и ответы на него могут пригодится многим, поэтому лучше  оформить его так, чтобы  было понятно многим. Иначе я могу дать ответ, что можно делать   LRESULT  ptr = reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>( result); и передать  его.  И вот кто то,в очереди проверок, решил, что ваш вопрос  "В текущем виде сложно понять", а я просто ответил вам.

Comment: @Stas, возможно, это не вызывало проблем, т.к. значение `result` было в пределах 32 бит. Посмотрел в багах nativeEvent и не нашел обсуждений о типе result. Но в примерах, где менялся `result` он был обычно `0`, например https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-82657, там еще `*result = HTCAPTION;`, но `HTCAPTION = 2` судя по https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest Да и сомневаюсь, что этих результатов там много, что нужно 64, плюс это сломало бы совместимость с 32

Comment: @gil9red у меня кастомный MessageHandler, который возвращает различные адреса 8-байтные и поэтому `*result = SendMessage(...)` не работает в Qt5. Думаю, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой тоже, не даром же поменяли в Qt6. Так вот интересно, как это в Qt5 обходили